# Refugee Passport / Refugee Travel Document from France to London

Tags: visas, uk, refugees

I am from Mali, and I have a Refugee Travel Document, a *TVR* as we say in French, otherwise called a "refugee passport." Do I need a visa to go to London?

Answer (score 7):

You will need a UK visa to enter the UK.

[This UK government page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-visa-requirements-list-for-carriers/uk-visa-requirements-for-international-carriers#holders-of-non-national-and-refugee-travel-documents) says:

> **Holders of non-national and refugee travel documents**
>
> If the passenger holds a refugee travel document issued by the UK they do not need a visa. *If the passenger holds any other non-national or refugee travel document they need a visa to enter the UK.* (emphasis added)

Comment: Do you know whether this requirement was there before the Brexit as well? GB was never a Schengen member which essentially mandates no general border controls whatsoever; but before Brexit, EU law may still have regulated travel differently.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica what is the relevance?

Comment: one might recall that Britain did Brexit *because they really hated refugees and wanted them to stay out*

Comment: @user253751 A recent change in regulations may be interesting information. While it won't help the OP it would provide context and related information as well as make the picture clearer for readers who knew of different but now obsolete regulations. In short, it would improve the usefulness of the answer to the general public, which is what this site strives for.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica My only knowledge of this document's creation or modification date is the statement under the main title at the top: "Updated 9 November 2022."

Comment: @user253751 that's not about refugees who are already settled in another country.  It's about refugees seeking to settle in the UK.